# AngularDart - stagehand web-angular material_ripple.scss error

Tags: angular-dart

Following [this](https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/guides/get-started)

And using cli

```
stagehand web-angular
pub get
webdev serve
```

Output:

```
[INFO] Setting up file watchers completed, took 25ms
[INFO] Waiting for all file watchers to be ready completed, took 201ms
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.2s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms
[SEVERE] angular_components|scss_builder on package:angular_components/material_ripple/material_ripple.scss:

Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
@import 'const/global',
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /private/var/folders/3p/8z23nlbs20qf291vlhjy1l0h0000gn/T/scratch_spaceuuJ2f0/packages/angular_components/css/material/_material.scss 19:9          @import
  /private/var/folders/3p/8z23nlbs20qf291vlhjy1l0h0000gn/T/scratch_spaceuuJ2f0/packages/angular_components/material_ripple/material_ripple.scss 5:9  root stylesheet
[SEVERE] angular_components|scss_builder on package:angular_components/material_slider/material_slider.scss:
```

And the list goes on with a lot more

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/271). A work around is to add the following dependency override to your project's `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependency_overrides:
  sass: 1.3.2
```